# Does this function even exist or is it deprecated?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have being trying to figure out, but in vain, whether this controller function even exists:
`$controller->field`. I have looked all around the internet and I haven't been able to find any documentation on function. Is it deprecated or does it even exist? Can anyone shed some light on it?

```
$Event = new EventsController;
$Event->constructClasses();
$data = $Event->field('title', "title = '".mysql_real_escape_string($this->params['form']['newtitle'])."'");
```

Comment: Did you try searching their API? http://api.cakephp.org/search/field

Comment: okay I tried to run this function using a model tag but it still gives me an error; I think my parameters have a problem; can anyone help me fix this problem?  Here is my code                               $data = $Event->field('title', "title = '".mysql_real_escape_string($this->params['form']['newtitle'])."'");

Comment: Isn't that the same code as that above (on the `$data` line)? Also, you should edit your question and add any new code or other additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a `Model` function, **not** a `Controller` one.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1028/field

Comment: Thanks, I felt suspicious that this should have been a model function; I am such a Nub!